# to write a binary data transfer (double) to csv as numeric not a string in R

Tags: r, csv

PC: i5, 8Gb. OS - win764 bit.

I need some guidance or hint how to save binary data transfer (integer and double columns) to csv file as numeric.

I mean when I open the file with the Explorer I see double as string but not as numeric. Integers seem to be Ok.
If I use 'read.csv2' for instance, I have got the correct data type inb the file saved.

Now I use 'writeBin' method to save data as binary vector. The method seems to have  a high speed to write data.

My script as follows:

```
library(iotools)
library(data.table)

df_size<-1000000
n<-  data.frame(x=1:df_size,y=rnorm(1:df_size),z=rnorm(1:df_size),w=c("fgdfgd"))
n[,4]<-as.character(n[,4])

file_output<-"test.csv"
if (file.exists(file_output)) file.remove(file_output)

file(file_output, ifelse(FALSE, "ab", "wb"))
zz <- file(file_output, "wb")

#to make a binary vector with colnames 
rnames<-as.output(rbind(colnames(n),""),sep=";",nsep="\t") #from iotools package
#to make the binary vector of the rest of the dataframe to be saved.
r = as.output(n, sep = ";",nsep="\t") #from iotools package

writeBin(rnames, zz)
writeBin(r, zz)
close(zz)

rm(zz)
gc()
```

Comment: I don't understand what the desired output is. CSV files are inherently text files. You can't have binary data in a CSV file.

Comment: @MrFlick
If I open csv file (by Excel or Notepad) I expect to have 4 columns:
x (integer), y(numeric),z(numeric) ,w(character). But in fact I will have the 1st column as numeric and the rest of columns will be as character (decimal sign is "." insted of ",")! but i need to have y and z column to be numeric.

Comment: You should be using write.csv rather than writeBin. The latter may be faster but it does not produce CSV files.

Comment: @MrFlick
thanks for your help. At least, you have confirmed my concern about methods and files compaitability.
In fact, fread is pretty good in dealing with such scorched csv files. So it is necessary to compare fread and read.csv.raw.
The entire mess was about to have fast written file with a friendly csv format ready to be used in Excel calculations, for instance.